# Setting Unique ID's of form elements on dynamic creation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a script to add a row dynamically. I am using the below function for it. The problem however is that it does creates the new row, but doesn't assigns unique ID's to the elements.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        var row_id = "row" + counter;
        console.log(row_id);
        new_elem = $("#new_row").clone().appendTo("#table_invoice tbody").show().attr("id", row_id);
        var button_id = "button" + row_id;
        var input_id = "row" + row_id;
        document.getElementById('row_id').firstChild.setAttribute('id',input_id);
        document.getElementById('row_id').firstChild.nextSibling.setAttribute('id',button_id);
        console.log(button_id);
        console.log(input_id);
        counter += 1;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table_invoice">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr id ="new_row" style="display:none;">
    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product ID" /></th>
    <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"">Add Product</button></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<a id="add_row" class="btn bt-default">Add New Row</a>
```

Also, I get the following error:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).firstChild.setAttribute is not a function

Can't figure out why this is not a valid function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jQuery this is how you do it: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uuhr6n42/)**

note that I've changed all the `row_id`s to counter, 'cause I think that is the intended approach.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 1;
        $("#add_row").click(function () {
            var row_id = "row" + counter;
            console.log(row_id);
            new_elem = $("#new_row").clone().appendTo("#table_invoice tbody").show().attr("id", row_id);
            var button_id = "button" + counter;
            var input_id = "input" + counter; //I think you meant "input" because if you set "row" at the beginning it would be duplicated of the tr
            $('#'+row_id).find('button').attr('id',button_id);
            $('#'+row_id).find('input').attr('id',input_id);
            console.log(button_id);
            console.log(input_id);
            counter++;
        });
    });
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. Can you point out why my code wasn't working?

Comment: firstly as @Utkanos mentioned `row_id` is a variable, so it must be taken out of the quotations, secondly honestly it's been a long time since I last used pure JS that I can not debug codes written in JS, so I don't know, there could be a lot of reasons why it didn't work! one thing I noticed in console though was that the output of `document.getElementById(row_id)` was null for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is it failed to find the element in the preceding methods, up to `firstChild`. Since it failed to find the element, the value in the chain at that point is undefined, which of course has no method `setAttribute`. Had it found the element you're looking for, the error wouldn't arise.

```
The problem is you're doing this:
```

document.getElementById('row_id')

when you mean

```
document.getElementById('row_id')
```

...i.e. `row_id` is a variable, and should be specified as such, not as a string.

Comment: OK then well you're going to need to do some debugging. With the DOM, that means starting by suspecting your selectors. Is `#new_row` coming back with anything? How about `#table_invoice tbody`? If either or all of those are failing to match elements, your code will break down.

Comment: When I said that a new row is indeed being created, then, yes obviously `#new_row` and `#table_invoice tbody` are working.